# How can I save a image with a base64 src to Google drive using javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-drive-api, google-api-js-client

I have an image tag like `<img src="base64......">` in my chrome extension.How can I send it to google drive by using javascript?
Does google drive's API support this?

Answer (score 1):

This is rather convenient, since you would have to base64 encode the image data to send it to Google Drive using the API. If you check out the [Google Drive javascript quickstart guide](https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-js), you can see how to create a MIME multipart request and use it to upload a file.

(the sample is probably too long to post here, but let me know if you have any trouble with it.)

Comment: Is it possible acess from chrome extension?It doesn't have a hostname.How can I configure JavaScript origins?